# How can I unsquash the buttons within my alertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I know I could solve this with a header but I'd rather not have one. Is there anyway to access the properties of the cancel button?

My code and an image of the AlertView is below.

[image]

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                if(view.getId() == (getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton" + (i+1), "id", "en.deco.android.livehud")))
                {


                    //alert.setTitle("Notes");

                    // Sets an EditText view to get user input 
                    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                    input.setText(table.seats[i].getPlayer().getNotes());
                    alert.setView(input);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                            if(view.getId() == (getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton" + (i+1), "id", "en.deco.android.livehud")))
                            {
                                table.seats[i].getPlayer().setNotes(input.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                      }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setMinimumWidth() does the job. The code above it is simply to generate display pixels rather than pixels.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                        float dp = 250f;
                        int pixels = (int) (metrics.density * dp + 0.5f);
                        input.setMinimumWidth(pixels);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd reckon you'd need to set your EditText to a defined width, or `fill_parent`/`match_parent`.

Comment: How? I can't see anything in the EditText documentation that allows this.

Comment: Assign a new LayoutParams object to the edit text.  It might be easier to use an inflated XML layout for this instead of one View.

Comment: I gave it a go, Fill Parent and Wrap_Content had no effect (contents already being wrapped by default?). Setting to a fixed size worked but I wanted the width to be expandable so my eventual solution was better for me. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can just set a view for your negative button, like this:

```
alert.setNegativeButton(R.id.cancelButton, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Some action to be done when clicked..

            }
        });
```

and you can create a layout with a button as a root like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel">
</Button>
```

where you will set the width of the button normally to `wrap_content`

**Edit**: there is also a  [AlertDialog.Builder setNegativeButton (int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNegativeButton%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)

Comment: I don't think this works. setNegativeButton doesn't appear to set our customView as the negativeButton. The first argument is merely for the text to be displayed on the button.
[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNegativeButton(java.lang.CharSequence, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

When trying this cancel is replaced by false and the button still has two rows. Is there any other way to set our own view as the negative button?